# Correct synthanx of an ASN.1 module

Tags: java, eclipse, asn.1

I wrote this ASN.1 module

```
-- Created: Mon May 06 19:38:15 CEST 2013 ASN-Module DEFINITIONS AUTOMATIC TAGS ::= BEGIN

Client ::= SEQUENCE { lientNumber INTEGER}

Server ::= SEQUENCE { lientNumber INTEGER, serverString String } END
```

The Eclipse ASN.1 plugin don't show me any error in the module but when i want to compile it with jac asn1 i get this error

> javacc.ParseException: Encountered "::=" at line 5, column 12. Was
>   expecting one of:
>       "{" ...
>       "DEFINITIONS" ...
>         at javacc.AsnParser.generateParseException(AsnParser.java:5351)     at javacc.AsnParser.jj_consume_token(AsnParser.java:5232)   at
>   javacc.AsnParser.ModuleDefinition(AsnParser.java:270)     at
>   javacc.AsnParser.Input(AsnParser.java:238)    at
>   javacc.AsnParser.main(AsnParser.java:83) arc - ASN.1 compiler
>   Copyright 1999 FORGE Research Pty Ltd
>
> usage: java AsnParser [-d directory] [-p package] source files...

Comment: What does the error message indicate the parser is looking for? Is that present in your ASN.1? Do you have any idea why it might not be seen by the compiler?  
   
`-- This is a comment. It begins with double dash.`

Comment: I correct the description but now i have another problem, can you take a look here please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16497292/asn-1-module-description

Answer (score 0):

From Information technology – Abstract Syntax Notation One (ASN.1): Specification of basic notation ([ITU-T X.680 (08/2015)](https://www.itu.int/itu-t/recommendations/rec.aspx?rec=x.680)); Chapter 13: Module definition:

```
ModuleDefinition ::= ModuleIdentifier DEFINITIONS EncodingReferenceDefault TagDefault ExtensionDefault " ::= "
BEGIN
  ModuleBody
  EncodingControlSections
END
```

It looks like you accidentally commented out the  `ASN-Module DEFINITIONS AUTOMATIC TAGS ::= BEGIN` part.