# ASN.1 module description

Tags: java, c, asn.1

I tried to use ASN.1 for a client server communication, but i'm not sure that i understand it correctly . The Client have to send an integer to the server, the server read it and send back a number and a String, the Client read them and send back a String the server read it and send back a String. It's something like this.

```
Client ---> server 1 integer

Server --> Client 1 integer
Server --> Client 1 String

Client ---> server 1 String
Server --> Client 1 String
```

I wrote the following ASN.1 module, I succeeded to generate the classes with jac asn1 but  I am not sure that the description of the module are correct because the two sequence are exactly the same. I m not sure if i have to put only the variable that i will send or recive or both.

> ```
> Demo-module DEFINITIONS ::=       -- Module-name DEFINITIONS ::= BEGIN
>
> BEGIN
> ```
>
> Client ::= SEQUENCE {
>
> clientInt     INTEGER ,
>
> serverInt    INTEGER ,
>
> serverString     BIT STRING ,
>
> clientString     BIT STRING ,
>          serverResponse     BIT STRING
>
> }
>
> Server ::= SEQUENCE {
>
> ```
> clientInt     INTEGER ,
> ```
>
> serverInt    INTEGER ,
>
> serverString     BIT STRING ,
>
> clientString     BIT STRING ,
>          serverResponse     BIT STRING
>
> }
>
> END                                      -- end of module, END
>   required

Comment: Yes, your "Server" and "Client" types are the same. So, why did you define two types representing essentially the same thing?

Comment: Note also, that ASN.1 does not define a protocol; it defines types, which may be used as messages. You have to decide what you want your messages to consist of, and how your protocol will use them.